# Save into database less and html

Tags: php, html, css, validation

I have a site developed in cakephp (PHP) and in a page a user can insert into a textarea less code (CSS) and in another textarea html code.

I want to store it into my database but the problem is:
- To validate this textarea to be usre that someone doesn't insert bad code (iframe with banner...) to preserve my security for my database and site, Does exist a parsing, a pattern , a regular expression for less code (CSS) and html code to save it into my database without possibility to insert insane code with PHP, cakephp(with model validation) or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: www.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: I know this page but I don't know which code is insane to save if I have html/css code @N.B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating and filtering html is complex problem and it might make sense to restore to tools already written. Here a nice comparision (it might be obviously a bit biased towards HTML Purifier but it covers functionalities and problems of different solutions pretty wall)

http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

If you not sure what tags should be banned the simplest approach is to filter against the list of tags you explicitly allow (whitelist)